# JLabel.setIcon() does not work as desired

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I am writing this Google Map component for Java Swing. I only need to use Google static map. I want the map to update based on a button action which reads user input, but the image which wrapped in a JLabel just does not update.

I cache the static map in **mapCache.jpg** and set the JLabel **mapContent**'s icon to it every time the **ActionListener** fires. But it just does not work. mapCache.jpg is updated on my system, but it just does not update in the program. I tried to remove imageicon or remove mapContent from JScrollPane, but neither of these worked. I suspect that JVM caches the image file. If so, how can I clear the cache?

Here's what's inside my class:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2243575060653389810L;
private String latlong;
private int zoomLevel;
private JLabel mapContent;
private ImageIcon mapImage;

public MapComponent(float lat, float lon, int zoom){
    latlong = validateLatlong(lat,lon);
    zoomLevel = validateZoomLevel(zoom);
    queryMap();

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mapImage = new ImageIcon("mapCache.jpg");
    mapContent = new JLabel(mapImage);
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(mapContent);
    add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel inputPane = new JPanel();
    JLabel latLabel = new JLabel("Latitude: ");
    final JTextField latText = new JTextField(""+lat);
    JLabel longLabel = new JLabel("Longitude: ");
    final JTextField longText = new JTextField(""+lon);
    JLabel zoomLabel = new JLabel("Zoom Level: ");
    final JTextField zoomText = new JTextField(""+zoomLevel);
    zoomText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,15));
    JButton mapGo = new JButton("Go");
    mapGo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try{
                queryMap(Float.parseFloat(latText.getText()), Float.parseFloat(longText.getText()), Integer.parseInt(zoomText.getText()));
                mapImage.setImage(new ImageIcon("mapCache.jpg").getImage());
                mapContent.setIcon(null);
                mapContent.setIcon(mapImage);  // Doesn't work!
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    inputPane.add(latLabel);
    inputPane.add(latText);
    inputPane.add(longLabel);
    inputPane.add(longText);
    inputPane.add(zoomLabel);
    inputPane.add(zoomText);
    inputPane.add(mapGo);
    add(inputPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    setVisible(true);
}

private void queryMap(){
    try {
        String imageUrl = "http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center="+latlong+"&zoom="+zoomLevel+
                "&size=1000x750&maptype=roadmap&markers="+latlong+
                "&key=ABQIAAAAgb5KEVTm54vkPcAkU9xOvBR30EG5jFWfUzfYJTWEkWk2p04CHxTGDNV791-cU95kOnweeZ0SsURYSA&format=jpg";
        System.out.println(imageUrl);
        String destinationFile = "mapCache.jpg";
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }
        is.close();
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void queryMap(float lat, float lon, int zoom){
    latlong = validateLatlong(lat,lon);
    zoomLevel = validateZoomLevel(zoom);
    queryMap();
}

private String validateLatlong(float lat, float lon){
    lat = Math.min(lat, 90);
    lat = Math.max(lat, -90);
    lon = Math.min(lon, 90);
    lon = Math.max(lon, -90);
    return lat+","+lon;
}

private int validateZoomLevel(int zoom){
    zoom = Math.min(zoom, 15);
    zoom = Math.max(zoom, 1);
    return zoom;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageIcon`, uses a `Image` as it's backing source, the `Image` caches it's image data in memory.  You need to `flush` the image data before you try reapplying it to the label

```
mapContent.setIcon(null);

mapImage.getImage().flush();
mapContent.setIcon(mapImage);  // Doesn't work! - Does now :)
```

I'd also recommend that you have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and handle your resources better, for example...

```
try (InputStream is = url.openStream(); OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile)) {
    byte[] b = new byte[2048];
    int length;
    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, length);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer When I do flush before setIcon, my icon disappears altogether. Any ideas?

Comment: @called2voyage The only thing I can think of is that the icon no longer exist (or is still been reloaded)

Answer (score 2):

The image is cached you need to flush it using:

```
icon = new ImageIcon(...);
icon.getImage().flush();
label.setIcon( icon );
```

Or you can just using ImageI/O to read the image:

```
label.setIcon( new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File(imageName) ) ) );
```